# Functions of diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

I am studying linear algebra from notes for a mathematical physics course and the section on diagonal matrices says that if $M$ is a diagonal matrix and $f$ is analytic, then $f(M)$ is equal to the matrix $M$ with the function $f$ applied to all its diagonal entries. The notes then say this can be shown using Taylor expansion.

I'm confused by this. $f(M)$ seems ill-defined. So do its derivatives. So how do you use a Taylor expansion to show the above?

Comment: Find the Taylor series of $f(x)$ and then plug in $M$.

Comment: You mean the Taylor series about the 0 scalar and then plug in the matrix as the value? Why is that correct?

Comment: It’s the usual hand-wave when working with infinite series: treat it as a formal power series, see what the result should be *if* the series converges, then worry about convergence (or not).

Answer (score 1):

If$$f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots,$$then$$f(M)=a_0+a_1M+a_2M^2+\cdots\tag1$$But if$$M=\begin{pmatrix}d_1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&d_2&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&d_3&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&d_n\end{pmatrix},$$then $(1)$ is equal to$$a_0\operatorname{Id}_n+a_1\begin{pmatrix}d_1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&d_2&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&d_3&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&d_n\end{pmatrix}+a_2\begin{pmatrix}{d_1}^2&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&{d_2}^2&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&{d_3}^2&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&{d_n}^2\end{pmatrix}+\cdots,$$which is just$$\begin{pmatrix}f(d_1)&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&f(d_2)&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&f(d_3)&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&f(d_n)\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ok, but the first equation is only true if the function f converges in the neighborhood of 0 (I'm assuming you are expanding about 0 though it doesn't matter) containing z. For instance, if there is a discontinuity between 0 and z you can't do that. But matrices aren't even in the same metric space as the real number 0. So why can you do that?

Comment: @azani If you really believe in “matrices aren't even in the same metric space as the real number $0$” (whatever that means) then, for you, talking about $f(M)$ doesn't even make sense, right?!

Comment: @azani it seems to me that the issue you're getting hung up on is what it means for a sequence of matrices to converge.  One way to think about it is this: we say that $\sum_{k=1}^N a_k M^k$ has a limit as $N \to \infty$ if each entry of the matrix approaches some limit.